# Какие разделители можно использовать в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, таблицы

Есть таблица, в которой должны храниться данные о местах в кинотеатре.
В качестве первичного ключа выбран ID места, который предполагается записать в виде: ряд.место. Например, 7.10

Возможно ли использование разделителя между числами в виде точки (или любого другого знака) в первичном ключе?

Comment: А почему бы не разделить ряд и место в отдельные колонки?